# Intuition for 2 commutation relations related to the Poincare group

Tags: commutator, poincare-symmetry

For some commutation relations related to the Poincare group, there are intuitive way of understanding it. For example, $[J_i,H]=0$ can be understood as the conservation of angular momentum along i direction by the Heisenberg equation. Another example is $[J_i,K_j]=i\hbar \epsilon_{ijk}K_k$, which I intuitively understand as an infinitesimal rotation of the $K_j$ operator in the Hilbert space about an axis where  $J_i$ points, resulting in a change in the operator in the k direction, $K_k$.

Are there similar interpretation for the following two:

$$[K_i,P_j] = iH \delta_{ij}$$
$$[K_i,H] =iP_i$$

Comment: Those relations say how $P$ and $H$ change (first order approximation) when changing the speed of the reference frame passing from an unertial reference frame to a different inertial one.

Comment: The commutator of two boosts is very interesting: It’s a rotation! See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner_rotation

Comment: If you don’t understand Valter’s comment, look at the Lorentz transformations for energy and momentum to first order in the relative velocity.

Comment: @ValterMoretti thanks for the intuitive explanation!

Comment: @G.Smith thanks for bringing up the commutation of $[K_i,K_j]=i\hbar \epsilon_{ijk} J_k$!